# Search for hyperlink field content CSOM

Tags: csom, column, hyperlink

Having a site column of type 'Hyperlink or picture" which is configured as hyperlink my requirement is to **search for content in this hyperlink column in a CSOM Applet**. 
Now I wonder

- do I have to create a separate managed property for this?
- which technique would be appropriate (KeyWordQuery in a javascript function or are there any jquery templates or better use REST)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works with keywordquery using the managed property which has been generated for the hyperlink column. For example to search for a specific file within a javascript applet we could execute:

```
function startSearch() {
SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.Search.js", "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery", function () {
    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext);
    keywordQuery.set_queryText("nameOfManagedPropertyOWSURLH:http://servertest.com/librarytest/filename.docx");
    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);
    results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
});
```

}

Finally we loop through the results delivered by the search engine

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    $.each(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows, function () {...});
}
```